# Does sickness improve?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I struggle to explain the situation when a person asks me about someone who has been sick and has become a bit better.

**For example:** Peter has been sick and after a period of time he becomes better. 
For that situation if James comes to me and asks me "Joseph! How is Peter? Is he sick now?"

I want to say that his sickness is improving to mean that he is getting better. Does that mean that? Or do I need to describe his sickness in a different way?

Comment: *'He's getting better.'*

Comment: "His **condition** (not sickness) is improving." Even just "He is improving."